# Sphinx Documentation - Exclude class variables for all the modules in the hierarchy

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm trying to remove all the class variables from my Sphinx documentation (because I haven't documented them and it doesn't look good if there's only a list of them) for all the classes of my project including the modules in the folders.
Is there an easy way to do it without having to exclude each one of them?

P.S.: I'm a beginner at this, so the answer could be something easy. Also, this could already be answered, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: If the class variables aren't documented (no docstrings), they should not appear in the output if the `undoc-members` option is NOT used. https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html

Comment: Thanks for answering!
They aren't documented but I get them in the html files. Is there any way to remove all the class variables even if they are documented? Maybe that could work...

Comment: I think you need to provide an example. How can we reproduce the problem? Do you use the `undoc-members` option or not?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:no-undoc-members:` to tell sphinx to ignore the undocumented (in your case the class) variables.

```
:undoc-members: (no value)
    If set, autodoc will also generate document for the members not having docstrings:
```

Here is the documentation - https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-option-automodule-undoc-members

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, but in which file am I supposed to type in ":undoc-members:" ?  seems like `conf.py` has no effect when autodoc is in play.